# Pass Values from an eCommerce Checkout Page to Thank You Page for Google Analytics tracking

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce, kajabi

I need help figuring out how to pass values from my checkout page to a thank you page, and configure a goal in Google Analytics that can accurately capture revenue for enhanced ecommerce tracking. Right now I'm only capturing Transactions, where the GA Goal is set to the thank you page loading.

I'm using Kajabi for everything (content management and order management system). They unfortunately don't have a true order confirmation page (like Shopify) where all of the details from the checkout page submission are summarized and Google Analytics can pull from.

My Checkout Page : https://www.advancerunning.com/offers/GBqJ4cPY/checkout

Thank You Page : https://www.advancerunning.com/thank_you/GBqJ4cPY

Two Asks (either is helpful)

1. How do I pass values from the checkout page to the thank you page?
2. How do I configure a goal in GA to capture this data for Enhanced Ecom Tracking?

Happy to provide additional context if needed!

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you pass values to the purchase page but I can point you in the direction of a post I wrote to help capture a basic transaction in Universal Google Analytics. You will find it [here](https://albanyanalytics.com/2020/03/25/a-simple-guide-for-implementing-google-analytics-transaction-tag/).

I do hope it helps. If not, please get in touch and I will point you to the big guys in this game. They write very helpful posts.

Comment: Thanks for answering and sharing that post Ateeq. While this is useful for capturing a basic transaction, I need to be able to have GA read all of the transaction details from the thank you page, which requires them to be passed from checkout to thank you somehow. If you have a suggestion on someone who might have expertise in that, please let me know!